# mobile application in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

how to switch off remote server by sending sms from mobile using asp.net

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us the work done by you till now then you may get some help.

Comment: How about sms to someone at home to ask them to power off the PC for you? Perhaps your neighbor can help too. Just kidding. :P But seriously, we'll need a lot more information from you to help us to help you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Put your asp.net application on the same server which you need to switch off. Grant full-trust to application. Write and HttpHandler that will receive SMS push from your SMS gateway. Write the code to switch off the server when proper sms is received. There are various techniques to switch off windows machines - you can search google for that.

Answer (score 1):

The sms gateway providers usually present the option of calling a URL that you specify when someone sends a message to you.

Assuming you have ASP.NET on the server you want to shut down and that it is accessible from the Internet you can call

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "-s -t 00")
```

in the ASP.NET application that receives the call from the SMS gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't get much response [last time you asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807692/mobile-application-in-asp-net); you still haven't provided enough information, so I wouldn't expect much to change this time around. Perhaps you could respond to some of the responses to the original question and explain why they're not suitable, or provide more detail so that we can provide a better answer?

I think you want rentacoder.com (but first, you'll need to develop more of a problem spec - for instance, you'll probably want to find a service that can receive the SMS and turn it into something like an email that the application can process - unless you're planning on embedding a GSM modem into the computer running this app, in which case you'll want to figure out what modem you're going to use so the developer can figure out how to interface with it)